# using $(this) in animate function

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-animate

```
$('.balloon').animate({top:30} ,1000);
$('.balloon').animate({top:10} ,1000);
```

I can do above successfully. Plz have a look at [**complete code and execution at fiddle**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/cRs9f/)

But I want above to work with generic top position like following. But when i do it gives me error `TypeError: a.ownerDocument is undefined`

```
$('.balloon').animate({top:$(this).css('top')+20} ,1000);
$('.balloon').animate({top:$(this).css('top')-20} ,1000);
```

Comment: `$(this)` in your code is for parent of `.balloon` you need to use `$.each` function

Comment: Yes. tell me plz how, if you can guide more. I try myself meanwhile. Thanks

Comment: i just posted my answer hope this what u looking for ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can be simplified:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    (function foo () {
        $('.balloon').stop(true).animate({top: "+=30"}, 1000, function () {
            $(this).stop(true).animate({top: "-=30"}, 1000, foo);
        });
    })();
});
```

You can use `+=30` to add `30px` to the top position. Same for `-30px`.

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/cRs9f/2/)

Comment: `IIFE` = Immediately Invoked Function Expression

Comment: Being a recursive function I have chosen this way. It's just shorter and looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

you need to work with `$.each` jquery function

this is Example http://fiddle.jshell.net/cRs9f/1/

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var downs = true;
    setInterval (function()
    {

        $('.balloon').each(function(){

          if(downs)
          {

               $(this).animate({top:30} ,1000);
               $(this).animate({top:$(this).css('top')+20} ,1000);
                downs =false;

          }else
          {
            $(this).animate({top:10} ,1000);
            $(this).animate({top:$(this).css('top')-20} ,1000);
            downs =true;
          }


        });

    },1000);
});
```